# Error in Android game for onTouchEvent

Tags: android

Can anyone help me to fix this error on `getPointerCount()`, `getX()`, and `getY()`?

> Multiple markers at this line
>
> The method `getPointerCount()` is undefined for the type `MotionEvent`

**Code**

```
int pointerIndex;
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
{
    float xPosition1 = 0;
    float yPosition1 = 0;
    float xPosition2 = 0;
    float yPosition2 = 0;

    for (pointerIndex = 0; pointerIndex < event.getPointerCount(); pointerIndex++) //Error
    {
    if (pointerIndex == 0)
    {
        xPosition1 = event.getX(pointerIndex);// Error
        yPosition1 = event.getY(pointerIndex);//Error
    }

    if (pointerIndex == 1)
    {
        xPosition2 = event.getX(pointerIndex);//Error
        yPosition2 = event.getX(pointerIndex);//Error
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll want to include the output of logcat: capture the exception and paste it here after editing your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getPointerCount()` is available starting from API level 5. If you use any SDK older than Android 2.0, you'll get that error.